# What is the standard testing suite that ships with Rails 5 called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like it shouldn't be this confusing (which might just mean I'm looking in the wrong place), but what is the standard testing suite for Rails called?

I thought it was Test::Unit, but the last mention I find of that is in [v3.2.8](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/testing.html#brief-note-about-test-unit)? The [Railsguides testing page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) says "Rails Meets Minitest" but I don't know if that means they both work or one is the other. There is also a [minitest-rails gem](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) which makes it seem like you need a separate gem to run minitest.

I seem to be in the minority not using RSpec so I'd like to be able to properly ask/search for the right testing suite when I have questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActiveSupport::TestCase` [is inherited from `Minitest::Test`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/34fe2a4fc778d18b7fe6bdf3629c1481bee789b9/activesupport/lib/active_support/test_case.rb#L14-L15).

AND it uses itself for its own tests: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/34fe2a4fc778d18b7fe6bdf3629c1481bee789b9/activesupport/test/test_case_test.rb

Pretty meta, huh? :)

Comment: Nice one. Love your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

MiniTest replaced Test::Unit and now also comes preinstalled with Ruby.

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit.html

> Test::Unit is an implementation of the xUnit testing framework for
>   Ruby.
>
> If you are writing new test code, please use MiniTest instead of
>   Test::Unit.
>
> Test::Unit has been left in the standard library to support legacy
>   test suites.